# deploy laravel project on heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku, deployment

I deploy laravel on heroku so I have this error:

**403 Forbidden**

**You don't have permission to access this resource.**

on the other hand I deploy laravel new project and it's work correctly
so what should i do to solve this problem .
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when I add Procfile on the project the deployment is comming correctly